# Serialize python dataDict to json object

Tags: python, json, django

I have made a dataDict after processing some data in my view which i retrieved from models. I want to serialize the dataDict and send it back using HttpResponse.

```
dataDict = 'cpu='+str(cpu_count)+'&memory='+str(memory_size)+'&count='+str(count)+''
qdict = QueryDict(dataDict)
```

when i print the qDict it gives the following output.

```
<QueryDict: {u'count': [u'77'], u'cpu': [u'187'], u'memory': [u'352256']}>
```

now i want to serialize the qdict and send it back as json data. any idea.

Comment: use the, data = serialize("json", qdict) gives me error AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '_meta'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard library has json module to handle such tasks:

```
import json
json_string = json.dumps(qdict.dict())
```